# Unable to run a simple SMTP server

Tags: python, smtplib

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

```
import smtplib

senders='jsujith1311@gmail.com'
password="ekjhgisxavzw"#Not Original Password
connection=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
connection.starttls()
connection.login(user=senders,password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=senders,to_addrs=senders,msg="HI")
connection.close()
```

Can anyone help with this

I need a simple smtp server running on my device initially, then i want to configutre it according to my needs.

Comment: Gmail does not listen to smtp port (25). You have to use `smtplib.SMTP_SSL`.

Comment: Tq, it worked after using smtplib.SMTP_SSL and removing starttls()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is to use
`connection = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com")`

and we have to remove the tls connection,I don't know why.But it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your password to an app password. Follow the below link for that: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: I changed it beforehand only,but still same error is being shown